# getting Whitelabel Error Page with status 500 for spring boot project

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am using spring boot and getting following error after deploying the project on cloud tomcat server when after some time running the link.

**Whitelabel Error Page**

**This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.**

**Thu Feb 01 16:20:29 IST 2018**

**There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No message available**

here is pom.xml file of project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.msoft</groupId>
<artifactId>crm</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>CRM</name>
<description>Customer Relationship Management</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

   <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>

 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
 </repositories>

 <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>


<packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

my controller-
    package com.msoft.crm.controller;

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.msoft.crm.model.Users;
import com.msoft.crm.service.IUserService;

@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public List<Users> hello(HttpServletRequest request) {
//      return userService.getAllUsers();
        return userService.getMenusByRole(1);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView home(ModelAndView modelAndView) {

        modelAndView.setViewName("login");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

I am not able to get where I am getting wrong. Code is working fine on local machine but not on cloud.

Adding stacktrace

```
Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.InfoContributorAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.AuditAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebClientAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.TraceRepositoryAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration



2018-02-01 20:20:26.560 DEBUG 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'metricWritersMetricExporter'
2018-02-01 20:20:26.562 DEBUG 4960 --- [  restartedMain] s.a.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Could not find default TaskScheduler bean

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:996) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.resolveSchedulerBean(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:278) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.finishRegistration(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:221) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:200) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:94) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:882) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at com.msoft.crm.CrmApplication.main(CrmApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]

2018-02-01 20:20:26.562 DEBUG 4960 --- [  restartedMain] s.a.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Could not find default ScheduledExecutorService bean

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:996) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.resolveSchedulerBean(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:278) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.finishRegistration(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:200) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:94) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:882) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at com.msoft.crm.CrmApplication.main(CrmApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]

2018-02-01 20:20:26.562  INFO 4960 --- [  restartedMain] s.a.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : No TaskScheduler/ScheduledExecutorService bean found for scheduled processing
2018-02-01 20:20:26.562 DEBUG 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.resource.ResourceUrlProvider     : Looking for resource handler mappings
2018-02-01 20:20:26.562 DEBUG 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'resourceHandlerMapping'
2018-02-01 20:20:26.562 DEBUG 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'faviconHandlerMapping'
2018-02-01 20:20:26.562 DEBUG 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.resource.ResourceUrlProvider     : Found resource handler mapping: URL pattern="/**/favicon.ico", locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], class path resource []], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@5ecbefa4]
2018-02-01 20:20:26.562 DEBUG 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.resource.ResourceUrlProvider     : Found resource handler mapping: URL pattern="/webjars/**", locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/webjars/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@77f913b4]
2018-02-01 20:20:26.562 DEBUG 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.resource.ResourceUrlProvider     : Found resource handler mapping: URL pattern="/**", locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@1002ee43]
2018-02-01 20:20:26.562 TRACE 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [servletConfigInitParams]
2018-02-01 20:20:26.562 TRACE 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [servletContextInitParams]
2018-02-01 20:20:26.562 TRACE 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
2018-02-01 20:20:26.562 TRACE 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
2018-02-01 20:20:26.562 TRACE 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [random]
2018-02-01 20:20:26.562 TRACE 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]]
2018-02-01 20:20:26.562 TRACE 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [refresh]
2018-02-01 20:20:26.562 TRACE 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [Management Server]
2018-02-01 20:20:26.562 DEBUG 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source
2018-02-01 20:20:26.612  INFO 4960 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http)
2018-02-01 20:20:26.612 TRACE 4960 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Publishing event in org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@62a0b341: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent[source=org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer@4bf86f7]
2018-02-01 20:20:26.612 DEBUG 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [server.ports] PropertySource with highest search precedence
2018-02-01 20:20:26.622 TRACE 4960 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Publishing event in org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@62a0b341: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent[source=org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication@422436cb]
2018-02-01 20:20:26.622 DEBUG 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar'
2018-02-01 20:20:26.622 DEBUG 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Creating new Restarter for thread Thread[main,5,main]
2018-02-01 20:20:26.622 DEBUG 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Immediately restarting application
2018-02-01 20:20:26.622 DEBUG 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@24e86b6d
2018-02-01 20:20:26.622 DEBUG 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Starting application com.msoft.crm.CrmApplication with URLs [file:/E:/CRM%20Application/latest_trunk/developed/ui/target/classes/]
2018-02-01 20:20:26.622  INFO 4960 --- [  restartedMain] com.msoft.crm.CrmApplication             : Started CrmApplication in 6.857 seconds (JVM running for 7.561)
```

CrmApplication.java class of main method-

```
package com.msoft.crm;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CrmApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(CrmApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(CrmApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: show your stacktrace

Comment: @Patrick I have edited the question and added stacktrace.

Comment: Where is the class with your main method ?

Comment: you are using spring-data-rest, try to replace Controller annotation by RepositoryRestController annotation, more information here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_repository_rest_controller_method_cors_configuration

Comment: @MonsifMabrouk replacing RepositoryRestController is not working in this case.

Comment: @NehaVaidya check the differences between your server's configuration and local (Tomcat, java version..), it's not very commong to package springboot app as war, try to change that to jar and use springs embedded tomcat.

Comment: Forwarded comment as requested by user @P.K.  I faced this issue when I was inserting wrong number of values (4) into the database. My constructor however had 5 parameters. On modifying the schema and the query to include that additional column, the error was resolved.